# what is the difference between *(&ptr) and *(ptr)

Tags: c

In following example,
when I tried to use `ptr` or `&ptr` in the `printf` it has printed the address of `a`.

```
int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int *ptr = &a;
    printf("%d", ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

but why is it printing two different outputs for `*(&ptr)` and `*(ptr)` when I use them in the `printf` statement?
I mean in the following code if it prints same output for `ptr` and `&ptr` then why `*(ptr)` is not equal to `*(&ptr)`?

Comment: it's doing that because they're different things.

Comment: `&ptr` takes the address of the pointer variable itself.

Comment: `&ptr` is not the address of `a`; it's the address of `ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

This code does not print the same output for ptr and &ptr:

As far as I can guess, it will print two different unsigned longs (the size of a 32-bit pointer) or unsigned long longs (the size of a 64-bit pointer) with a 32 (64) difference, since they both target data that were allocated one right after the other ont the stack.

That's if you try to print ptr and &ptr.

Printing *(ptr) and *(&ptr) will print thus respectively an int and a pointer (as above).

TL/DR: It is normal that different data is printed for two different variables.

PS: I am surprized your compiler let you print a pointer as an %d.